# Discrete Probability: alice and mary take a math exam

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So I have a problem here, I know the answer but I have no idea how to solve it. This is one of a sample problem given to us by our prof. Can someone please help me out how to figure this problem out?

Alice and Mary take a math exam. The probability of passing this exam for Alice and Mary is 2/3 and 3/5, respectively. What is the probability that at least one of them will pass the exam?

Comment: Your answer is $1-P(\mbox{both will not pass})$. What is the probability A will not pass? M will not pass? Both will not pass?

Comment: Realistically, a little more than $2/3$.  Most likely, the problem was written to assume independence, but that would be an awkward assumption here (unless they're taking different exams)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrt of all we have to assume independence (understood hypothesis)

Let's set the events

- "0= not pass"
- "1=pass"

And let's analyze all the possible probabilities

$$\mathbb{P}[0;0]=\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{2}{5}=\frac{2}{15}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[0;1]=\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{3}{5}=\frac{3}{15}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[1;0]=\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{2}{5}=\frac{4}{15}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[1;1]=\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{3}{5}=\frac{6}{15}$$

As a verification

$\frac{2}{15}+\frac{3}{15}+\frac{4}{15}+\frac{6}{15}=1$

Now you can answer to any question they ask you, as you know the probability of every elementary event of the event space

Comment: Well that did just cleared things up, thanks a lot for enlightening me